# Simple JS function Not Working

Tags: php, functions, javascript

I have been trying to get a simple JS function to work for the longest while but its just not working. Console says "test is not a function.

```
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$return_survey_url.'" id="return_url">';
echo '<form action="http://www.example.com/test.php" onsubmit="return test();" method="post" target="votar">';
echo '<textarea name="tweet" rows="8" cols="10" maxlength="130"></textarea>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="test"/>';
echo '<iframe name="votar" style="display:block; width: 500px; height: 500px;"></iframe>';    
echo '</form>';
```

The below that I close the PHP tag and have a simple script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function test() {
        alert('thank you');
         var return_url = document.getElementById('return_url').value;
         window.location.href= return_url;

     }
  </script>
```

Whenever I click the submit button console spits out that it is not a function. I am trying to get this to work within a CPT template, this code only needs to happen on that specific template. This same code works here:

https://jsfiddle.net/n7zd1hw8/

Comment: your code works for me with a copy/paste into a template file, you'll have to give some more context as to where you've got this code exactly.

Comment: As soon as I click the button console tells me that test is not a function http://pastebin.com/VTU9eDMZ

Answer (score 1):

Added ID to form submit botton and removed onSubmit event:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$return_survey_url.'" id="return_url">';
echo '<form action="http://www.example.com/test.php" method="post" target="votar">';
echo '<textarea name="tweet" rows="8" cols="10" maxlength="130"></textarea>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="test" id="test"/>';
echo '<iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe>';    
echo '</form>';
```

Added JS in noconflict mode and called function when submit button click:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
    $( "#test" ).click(function() {
      alert('some message');
      var return_url = document.getElementById('return_url').value;
      window.location.href= return_url;
    });

});
</script>
```